# EC2 SSH'ing into other SSH and running bash script

Tags: python, bash, amazon-ec2

I have Python program sshs into a different EC2 box and runs a bash script. However it will only run the bash script if it's in the default directory upon logging in.  Here's some code.

```
import boto3
import botocore
import paramiko

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_client.download_file('mybucket','keys/mykey.pem', '/tmp/mykey.pem')

k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('/tmp/mykey.pem')
c = paramiko.SSHClient()
c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

print "Connecting to Box"
c.connect( hostname = '99.99.9999', username = 'centos',pkey = k )
print "Connected to Matching Box"

commands = [
    "cd /dir1/dir2/dir3/",         #<-  This isn't working
    "pwd",
    "chmod +x file.sh",
    "nohup ./file.sh > logs/myprogram"
    ]
for command in commands:
    print "Executing {}".format(command)
    stdin , stdout, stderr = c.exec_command(command)
    print stdout.read()
    print stderr.read()

quit() #use return when putting on the handler
{
    'message' : "Script execution completed. See Cloudwatch logs for complete output"
}
```

Problem is it's not changing the directory.  The PWD keeps returning the default and then obviously an error message raised since my bash script isn't present. It's a Centos build EC2 instance, not sure if that matters much.  If I login normally and run the same change directory command, it works 100%.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: How about merging all commands into one line like `cd /dir1/dir2/dir3/; pwd; chmod ...` ? Not that I know the exact cause, only a wild guess that could help with debugging.

Comment: Hey it's better than where I am now.  I'll give it  a try and report back.

Comment: If still not solving the problem, try adding a line `sudo -i` at the beginning of commands.

Comment: @ChangQian That did the trick.  If you add as an answer I'll accept. Thanks all.

Comment: Done and added reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command:
`A new Channel is opened and the requested command is executed.`

If you login normally, all 4 of your commands will be executed in the same channel, so the `cd` takes effect. But when you execute them in a loop of `exec_command()`s, 4 channels, probably 4 `bash` processes, are spawned and destroyed, so the `$PWD` does not persist.

```
command = 'cd /dir1/dir2/dir3/; pwd; chmod +x file.sh; nohup ./file.sh > logs/myprogram'
stdin, stdout, stderr = c.exec_command(command)
```

That will do the trick.